# conversion from PDF to TIFF does not work

Tags: python

I want to convert my test.pdf file to test.tyff and save it in another folder.
But unfortunately, both methods do not work, the program either freezes or simply does not produce anything

```
def transformPDFtoTIFF():
    pdfFile = r'C:\Users\MyOrder\test.pdf'
    tiffFile = r'C:\Users\NewOrder\test.tiff'
        os.system("gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r100 -q -sOutputFile= " + pdfFile + tiffFile )
        # os.system("gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r100 -q -o " + pdfFile + tiffFile )
)
```

Comment: Print the command line and check it before feeding it into `os.system`!

Comment: Can you add the console errors here?

Comment: Have you tried the command on the cmd-console without using python? something like `gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r100 -q -sOutputFile= " + pdfFile + tiffFile`, whereas the last part looks wrong ...

Comment: gs: The term "gs" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the
Name, or whether the path is correct (if included), and try again.
In line: 1 character: 1
+ gs -sDEVICE = tiffgray -r100 -q -o C: \ Users \ MyOrder\ test.pdf C: \ Users \ e907 ...

Comment: + ~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (gs: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
 

Suggestion [3, General]: The command gs was not found. However, it is available at the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, enter ". \ Gs" instead. For more information, see "get-help about_Command_Precedence".

Comment: I get this if I enter into the Terminal what is in the OS

Answer (score 1):

your current command is

`os.system("gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r100 -q -sOutputFile= " + pdfFile + tiffFile )`

The error messages you show in comments are normally powershell errors thus should not be in a standard windows console where gswin##c is expected to run !

NOTE:- GS is not the normal .exe for windows it is usually gswin32c.exe or gswin64c.exe so check which one works from your standard users windows cmd prompt.

As suggested check first at cmd> prompt that

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r100 -o"C:\Users\MyOrder\test.tif" "C:\Users\MyOrder\test.pdf"
```

works well, if it does not then check Ghostscript was installed correctly. You say you want tiff from pdf so the command sequence

`-q -sOutputFile= " + pdfFile + tiffFile`

should much simpler be `-o" + tiffFile + " " + pdfFile + "`